# Remove keys with false values from array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an associative array with a whole pile of `true`/`false` values.

I am trying to remove all keys where the values are `false`.

So if the array is

```
array(
  'key1' => true,
  'key2' => false,
  'key3' => false,
  'key4' => true
);
```

I want to end up with

```
array(
  'key1' => true,
  'key4' => true
);
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
$array = array_filter(array(
    'key1' => true,
    'key2' => false,
    'key3' => false,
    'key4' => true
));
```

[array_filter()](http://php.net/array-filter)

Comment: A generation of coders that reference the manual first would be nice too

Answer (score 0):

see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php , combine this with a foreach and you have what you need.

also, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Answer (score 0):

```
for (x=0; x < array.count; x++)
{
     if (key.value == false)
     {
          unset($arr[x]);
     }
}
```

Just psuedocode, so I hope you know what I mean.

Comment: That seems to be Java (or something), not PHP

Comment: Wouldn't know. Like I said, it's meant to be just psuedocode.

Comment: No problem, sorry for the confusion. :P

Answer (score -1):

Arraydecleration (using PHP 5.4 array shorthand):

```
$arr = ['key1' => TRUE, 'key2' => FALSE, 'key3' => FALSE, 'key4' => TRUE];
```

Then remove all keys and values from array where value == FALSE (optionally use strict comparison "==="):

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
    if ($value == FALSE)
        unset($arr[$key]);
```

Print results:

```
print_r($arr);
```

This last line prints "Array ( [key1] => 1 [key4] => 1 )".

Comment: A little bit late on the train, but this will remove `""`, `0`, `0.0`, `null` and `[]` too. That may be intended, but it's not clear. I see the phrase "optionally use `===`", but it is not an option, but a different behaviour and therefore a different result.